# Hello good this I get this when I try to execute the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I try to execute that code I get this error: TypeError: mybuttonsmsg.createButtonCollector is not a function

---

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor('Verifícate para ver todo el servidor')
  .setDescription('Buenas, llegado a este punto deberás de verificarte para obtener al resto del servidor. Para verificarte, deberás de introducir el siguiente comando: `!verify` Si no funciona, puedes enviar un md a @Fontanero. Si el bot está apagado, espera a que se vuelva a encenderse. Si el problema persiste, contacta con cualquier miembro del staff.')

const botonrole = new disbut.MessageButton()
  .setStyle('blurple')
  .setLabel('<a:verify:884959804550963242> Verificate')
  .setID('boton_click')

const row = new disbut.MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents({ botonrole });

const mybuttonsmsg = await message.channel.send({ component: row, embed: embed })

const collector = mybuttonsmsg.createButtonCollector((button) => button.clicker.user.id === message.author.id, { time: 60e3 });
collector.on("collect", (b) => {
  console.log(b.id)
  if (b.id == "boton_click") {
    b.reply.defer()
    button.reply.send(`Has sido verificado éxitosamente`)
    const role = button.guild.roles.cache.get('884901954243924008')
    const member = button.clicker.member
    member.roles.add(role) 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing called as `createButtonCollector` within discord.js, although there is a [`TextChannel#createMessageComponentCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) method available to the `TextChannel` and [`Message#createComponentCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) method available to the `Message`

Here's an example:

```js
// Create a message component interaction collector
const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'button' && interaction.user.id === 'someId';
const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
collector.on('collect', i => console.log(`Collected ${i.customId}`));
collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
```

Comment: is that bro I want to do a verification by button what would I have to do?

Comment: Yes you can do that via a compeonentCollector just change the ButtonCollector to MessageComponentCollector and b.id to b.customId and youd be done